# Use sessions in django in order to check if someone is loged in or not

Tags: python, django, security

I tried to create a dictionary `key` in the `request.session`:

```
request.session['key'] = 1232354
```

When a user navigate into the website, I check if they have the `key` in order to know if they are logged in.

I'm new to Django and I am afraid that there is some big cons in this idea, like easily getting the web site hacked or something. Is there anything wrong about this idea?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide detailed information about your problem, a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what you did try before posting. Some examples are always useful. Please, check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question for more details as well.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to be the "use X library" guy, but if you're using Django you should be using [django.contrib.auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/) for handling authentication rather than rolling your own, unless you're very experienced with web development and computer security. Authentication is very sensitive in terms of security and Django's authentication system is very well-done and is IMO one of the main strengths of the framework.

Comment: i don't like it because it control a lot of stuff that i want to be in custom way

Comment: Do you mind if I ask which types of stuff you want to customize? I'm not very experienced myself but maybe I can help.